# How to add callback to useLazyQuery

Tags: javascript, callback, graphql

I'm doing the tutorial - https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/ with a lazy graphQL. I have a function which let me get data by click button with lazy query to server.
I wrapped it of anonymous function and put to onClick button.
Could you help me to add another function to callback of getDog, to add some actions after useLazyQuery will finished.

```
const [getDog, { loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(GET_DOG_PHOTO);
```

I tried

```
const [getDog, { loading, data }] = {
    useLazyQuery(CUSTOM_GQL);
    return // some actions with data and return;
}
```

does not compile

```
<button onClick={
   () => {
      getDog();
      return // some actions
          }
        }
```

some actions works only after second click.

Comment: real reason? ... on next render (with data) you can use condition `if( data ) ..` ... but fired on every further rerendering ...  use `useEffect` to run only on `data` change

Comment: @xadm Thank u for response. Could you write please example? Where and how do I apply  `useEffect`?

Answer (score 15):

'Classic' callback can be defined inside hook (see [API specs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/#uselazyquery))

```
const [getDog, { loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(GET_DOG_PHOTO, {
  onCompleted: (data) => {
    // some actions
  }
});

return (
  <button onClick={ () => getDog() )
```

... but in react and in functional components (with hooks) component function is rerun on changes to update view

```
const [getDog, { loading, data }] = useLazyQuery(GET_DOG_PHOTO);  

if( data ) {
  // 'callback'
}
```

... but this code can be run many times (by other changes) ... you can avoid that with `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // code run only on every `data` change
  if( data ) {
    // only when `data` not empty - after first and futher data loading
  }
}, [data]);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why no upvote. The correct answer and informative. Thank you.